# tput errors from Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano

Specifically I'm seeing

```
*** [err :: 198.x.x.x] tput:
*** [err :: 198.x.x.x] No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

This seemed to start after upgrading RVM and installing libksba per rvm requirements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bug and is already reported, it will be fixed with this ticket https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/727